# Can I put profanity words file inside app bundle?

Tags: ios, iphone, appstore-approval

I would like to clear a doubt is that, I have to do profanity filter on text so that I have decided to put a file inside the bundle having the list of abusive words ?

Everything is seems to fine. Now I would like to know is that can apple reject my app ?

We never show the list or that files anywhere in side the app.

Comment: Swapnil provides excellent guidance, but Stack Overflow is unable to answer this question in any authoritative way. The only way to know if Apple will reject your app is to submit it. Every time you submit an update, it is always possible that they will reject it, even if they accepted the same thing before. No amount of assurance from SO will ensure you will be accepted, and no amount of "I got rejected for something similar" will indicate that you will be rejected. Apple is fickle and reinterpret their own rules regularly.

Comment: Ultimately the question is "if Apple rejects this, what would we do in that case?" And then be prepared to do that if the situation arrises. Or wait for them to reject it, and then scramble to work with them.

Comment: I unfortunately agree with, and have experienced, everything @RobNapier has mentioned above. My answer is just a meek attempt to prepare for "what would we do in that case" scenario :)

Comment: In that spirit, i just edited ***"very diffucult to confidently answer"*** to ***"not possible to answer"*** ->  "can apple reject my app?" in my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to answer ***"can apple reject my app?"***, with a simple ***"NO."***, as apple very clearly says in [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/)

> This is a living document; new apps presenting new questions may result in new rules at any time. Perhaps your app will trigger this.

However, in the same document, under [User Generated Content (section 1.2)](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#user-generated-content) apple suggests

> Apps with user-generated content present particular challenges,
> ranging from intellectual property infringement to anonymous bullying.
> To prevent abuse, apps with user-generated content or social
> networking services must include:
>
> - A method for filtering objectionable material from being posted to the app

Meaning, what you are doing is not only ok, but is an expectation from apple, and your app should be accepted.

So, submit your app for review, and in case your app gets rejected for having these words in the code/bundle, be ready to very clearly explain

- how are you using these words
- (as you mention in this question) you never show the list or that file to the user anywhere inside the app